# Is http://example.com// handled differently than http://example.com/ for all clients?

Tags: html, http, url, browser, client

**Question:** Normally one gets the same HTML site for the URLs `http://example.com//` and `http://example.com/` (the first URL has two slashes in the end). I guess, I can configure my website in a way, that the served HTML differs between the two URLs. Is this always handled correctly by all clients, i.e. do all client send a get request starting with `GET // HTTP/1.1` in the first line? (Or are there clients/browser who shorten the request of `http://example.com//` to `GET / HTTP/1.1` with one slash?)

**Background of my question:** I want to implement a JavaScript version of my website using the [hash fragement](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) `#!`. In this version the whole content shall be loaded dynamically. I thought that URLs like `http://example.com/foo/bar/` shall become `http://example.com//#!/foo/bar/` (short URL in the end) whereby I serve under `http://example.com//` the JavaScript for this site version (which differs from `http://example.com/`). I just asked myself, whether this approach is theoretically possible or not concerning todays standards for URLs.

Comment: This is a server side issue, not a client side issue. And yes, you get the same result. Simply because the requests are mapped to the file system logic which treats '//' equally to '/' on all systems typically used as a base for an http server. Actually that is nothing you can configure, except by using a server side rewriting rule and regular expressions, so _before_ processing an actual request.

Comment: @arkascha: Using rewrite rules is exactly my plan for serving different HTML files. My question is: Do all clients always send two slashes if they see an URL like ``http://example.com//`` ? (Because if there is something like client-side URL simplification I cannot use rewrite rules...)

Comment: Well, I would expect that "all" clients (whatever that means) do send that, but better check yourself. Either use a network sniffer, or (easier), a debugging proxy, or even simply check the servers access log file and fire different browsers and other clients.

Comment: @arkascha: Unfortunately I have no access to all browser types now, but I guess you are right an I have to do it...

Comment: Definitely suggest cross-browser/os testing this before running with it, i've had issues in the past with linking to images for example with an erroneous `//` instead of `/` in the path working in chrome but not firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some results, I got so far:

- `Firefox (Version 28.0)`: **YES (sends two slashes)**
- `curl` (and I hope therefore also programs using `libcurl`): **YES (sends two slashes)**
- `wget`: **YES (sends two slashes)**
- `Chromium (Version 33.0)`: **YES (sends two slashes)**

Unfortunately I have no access to more browsers now. I will update this answer. But it would be good, if you can post some more experiences in the meanwhile ;-)

**Comment of @Kevin B:**

> Definitely suggest cross-browser/os testing this before running with it, i've had issues in the past with linking to images for example with an erroneous // instead of / in the path working in chrome but not firefox.